# For loop with Maxima

Tags: loops, for-loop, maxima

```
for i:1 thru 3 step 1 do;
posix:arithsum(li*cos(ri(t))),1,i-1)+(li*cos(ri(t))/2);
posiy:arithsum(li*sin(ri(t))),1,i-1)+(li*sin(ri(t))/2);
```

What I wanna do is to get 6 position functions(3 x and 3 y). It should give me values like following:

```
pos1x:l1*cos(r1(t))/2;
pos2x:l1*cos(r1(t))+l2*cos(r2(t))/2;
pos3x:l1*cos(r1(t))+l2*cos(r2(t))+l3*cos(r3(t))/2;
```

So, why my code is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things here. (1) `for` loop takes just one expression as its loop body; typically multiple expressions are combined into one as `(e1, e2, e3)` or `block(e1, e2, e3)`. Note that `for ... do;` isn't correct syntax, since it doesn't have a loop body -- the semicolon terminates the `for` expression. Note also that expressions in the body are separated by commas, not semicolons. (2) You can use subscript notation to index items; Maxima won't automatically construct symbol names such as `pos1x`. Instead, use subscript notation: `posx[1]`, `posy[i]`, etc.

Given that, here's a solution.

```
(%i1) load (functs);
(%o1) /Applications/Maxima.app/Contents/Resources/opt/share/maxima/5.41.0/shar\
e/simplification/functs.mac
(%i2) for i:1 thru 3 step 1 do
 (posx[i]:arithsum(l[i]*cos(r[i](t)),1,i-1)+(l[i]*cos(r[i](t))/2),
  posy[i]:arithsum(l[i]*sin(r[i](t)),1,i-1)+(l[i]*sin(r[i](t))/2));
(%o2)                                done
(%i3) [posx[1], posx[2], posx[3]];
       l  cos(r (t))  3 l  cos(r (t))                          l  cos(r (t))
        1      1         2      2                         1     3      3
(%o3) [-------------, ---------------, 2 (l  cos(r (t)) + -) + -------------]
             2               2             3      3       2          2
(%i4) [posy[1], posy[2], posy[3]];
       l  sin(r (t))  3 l  sin(r (t))                          l  sin(r (t))
        1      1         2      2                         1     3      3
(%o4) [-------------, ---------------, 2 (l  sin(r (t)) + -) + -------------]
             2               2             3      3       2          2
```

I am guessing that `l[i]` and `r[i]` should be subscripted too. I changed the parentheses in order to fix a syntax problem; if you intended something else, of course you can go ahead and change it again.

Note that in this formulation `posx` and `posy` are so-called undeclared arrays. Undeclared arrays are suitable for representing subscripted symbolic variables. You can get the list of elements via `listarray`.

Comment: Firstly, your effort is highly appreciated, now I just need to fix small problems, problem with maxima is that resources for it are really scarce.

Comment: You can also get help on the Maxima mailing list. See: https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/lists/maxima-discuss